# Unit testing for code isn't working for cs50 problem

Tags: python, unit-testing, cs50

I'm currently working on a Cs50 problem called Testing my Twitter. The code works very well and has no problems. But I'm having trouble trying to run a unit test on it.

this is my regular code that needs testing:

```
def shorten(word):
    tweet = input("Input: ")
    for letter in tweet:
        if not letter in ['A','E','I','O','U','a','e','i','o']:
            return letter
    print()
```

And this is my unit test code:

```
import twttr

def test_twttr():
    assert shorten('Hello') == 'Hll'
test_twttr()
```

I've run into a lot of errors and have reached this point in my code where it just says OK. I changed my code to have an error and I'm still getting the same message. Can someone please take a look and see what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems. You ignore the input `word` and instead prompt the user for a value. Then you return the first vowel found instead of removing that vowel from the word. You need to remove vowels and then reassemble a string for return. And its a trivial matter, but checking against a set is usually faster than checking against a list.

This operation can be done with a simple list comprehension instead.

```
def shorten(word):
    return "".join(c for c in word if c not in {'A','E','I','O','U','a','e','i','o', 'u'})
```